# asp:SqlDataSource vs ADO.NET coding with C#

Tags: asp.net

I really do not have time to learn new language, in my case asp.net, but would like to start developing website in asp.net. I do not want to use asp:SqlDataSource control. is it ok if i write in codebehind aspx: all database connections and other CRUD operations in ado.net and c#. I already know xhtml, javascript - jquery, css, xml, json, some knowledge in sever-side coding (before php). want to start coding, instead of learning messy asp.net controls. Please advise, or I have to sit and learn all bloody ways of using those asp.net controls?

Comment: You don't want to learn ASP.NET, but you want to develop with it? I don't get it. Go ahead and learn ASP.NET. You can create and manipulate controls in the mark-up and in the code-behind file. Learn how to do both. Learn about databound controls, and Eval() and Bind(). I find that specifying databound properties in the mark-up file is cleaner if you have a choice.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use SqlDataSource control and you can do everything in ado.net and C#.

However, on certain case, you will be able to save quite a bit of coding by using SqlDatasource.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel so bad about ASP.NET controls, why even aspire to use it? While you don't need to use any controls that the framework or third party offers, starting using anything new requires some learning. You don't need to use asp:SqlDataSource to build the data driven ASP.NET website but it seems like you have already shunned all the controls (not just this one) :)

Also, I would recommend looking in to ASP.NET MVC 3.0 if you are just starting. That would be more closer to what you have been doing so far.